# Infinite mutual information for continuous multidimensional random variables

Tags: continuous-data, mutual-information

I am struggling with understanding the notion of the infinity of the mutual information. Say, one has an multidimensional continuous Gaussian variable $(X_1, X_2...X_d)$. Why would the mutual information between this variable and one dimension of it (without loss of generality say $X_1$) be infinite?

Thank you

Comment: Have you tried to prove/disprove this statement? If so, could you add this proof to your question?

Comment: No, it is more of a thought experiment. I am not quite sure how to approach the proof. The intuition behind follows from the definition of the mutual information for continuous variables as discrete approximation with binning limiting to be finer (like in El Gamal book on information theory).